# IndexError: list index out of range. Не могу понять, из за чего выкидывает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

При вызове метода выкидывает ошибку IndexError: list index out of range
Не могу понять, из за чего выдает ошибку.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Classes/classes.py", line 101, in <module>
    print(get_car_list('file_csv.csv'))
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Classes/classes.py", line 79, in get_car_list
    car_params = row[0].split(';')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Метод:

```
 def get_car_list(path):
    car_list = []
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(file)
        for row in csv_file:
            car_params = row[0].split(';')
            if car_params[0] == 'car':
                car = Car(brand=car_params[1],
                          passenger_seats_count=car_params[2],
                          photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                          carrying=car_params[5])
                car_list.append(car)
            elif car_params[0] == 'truck':
                car = Truck(brand=car_params[1],
                            photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                            body_whl=car_params[4],
                            carrying=car_params[5])
                car_list.append(car)
            elif car_params[0] == 'spec_machine':
                car = SpecMachine(brand=car_params[1],
                                  photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                                  carrying=car_params[5],
                                  extra=car_params[6])
                car_list.append(car)
    return car_list
```

Содержимое CSV файла:

```
car_type;brand;passenger_seats_count;photo_file_name;body_whl;carrying;extra
car;Nissan xTtrail;4;f1.jpeg;;2.5;
truck;Man;;f2.png;8x3x2.5;20;
truck;Man;;f2.png;;20;
car;Mazda 6;4;f3.jpeg;;2.5;
;;;
spec_machine;Hitachi;;f4;;1.2;Легкая техника для уборки снега
```

Полный код:

```
import os
import csv


class CarBase:
    photo_file_names = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png']

    def get_photo_file_ext(self):
        if os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)[1] in self.photo_file_names:
            return os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)[1]
        else:
            return False

    def __init__(self, brand, carrying, photo_file_name,):
        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        try:
            self.carrying = float(carrying)
        except TypeError as err:
            print(err)
        else:
            self.carrying = carrying


class Car(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, carrying, photo_file_name, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(brand, carrying, photo_file_name)
        self.car_type = 'car'
        try:
            self.passenger_seats_count = int(passenger_seats_count)
        except TypeError as error:
            print(error)
        else:
            self.passenger_seats_count = int(passenger_seats_count)


def get_body_lwh(in_lwh):
    lwh = in_lwh.split('x')
    if len(lwh) != 3:
        lwh.clear()
        for i in range(3):
            lwh.append(0)
        return lwh
    else:
        try:
            for i in range(3):
                lwh[i] = float(lwh[i])
            return lwh
        except ValueError:
            for i in range(3):
                lwh.append(0)
            return lwh


class Truck(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, carrying, photo_file_name, body_whl):
        super().__init__(brand, carrying, photo_file_name)
        self.body_length = get_body_lwh(body_whl)[0]
        self.body_width = get_body_lwh(body_whl)[1]
        self.body_height = get_body_lwh(body_whl)[2]
        self.car_type = 'truck'

    def get_body_value(self):
        return self.body_length * self.body_width * self.body_height


class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, carrying, photo_file_name, extra):
        super().__init__(brand, carrying, photo_file_name)
        self.extra = extra
        self.car_type = 'spec_machine'


def get_car_list(path):
    car_list = []
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(file)
        for row in csv_file:
            print(row)
            print(type(row))
            car_params = row[0].split(';')
            if car_params[0] == 'car':
                car = Car(brand=car_params[1],
                          passenger_seats_count=car_params[2],
                          photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                          carrying=car_params[5])
                car_list.append(car)
            elif car_params[0] == 'truck':
                car = Truck(brand=car_params[1],
                            photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                            body_whl=car_params[4],
                            carrying=car_params[5])
                car_list.append(car)
            elif car_params[0] == 'spec_machine':
                car = SpecMachine(brand=car_params[1],
                                  photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                                  carrying=car_params[5],
                                  extra=car_params[6])
                car_list.append(car)
                
    return car_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_car_list('file_csv.csv'))
```

Comment: Приведите ошибку и содержимое файла в текстовом виде.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Проверяйте.

Comment: Попробую облегчить Вам задачу. Используйте библиотеку `pandas`. Получите из вашего `csv` нормальный структурированный `DataFrame` через `pandas.read_csv()` и спокойно дальше с ним работайте.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin
Тогда выкидывает вот такую ошибку:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: @Namerek
Это задание с Coursera, поэтому, не знаю, пройдет ли решение с библиотекой pandas, а не с csv, которую они рекомендовали

Comment: @VladislavChevtaev ошибка не воспроизводится с полным кодом https://repl.it/repls/SelfassuredRosybrownLegacy

Comment: Сделайте тупо `print(row)` прежде чем брать `row[0]`, вообще подозреваю у вас пустая строка туда как-то закралась

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, у меня Ваш код из вопроса полностью работает вот в такой интерпретации
Собственно я сам ваш код и не менял, только дописал то, чего не хватало для того, чтобы его у себя запустить

```py
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

SpecMachine = namedtuple(
    'SpecMachine',
    [
        'brand',
        'photo_file_name',
        'carrying',
        'extra'
    ]
)

Car = namedtuple(
    'Car',
    [
        'brand',
        'passenger_seats_count',
        'photo_file_name',
        'carrying'
    ]
)

Truck = namedtuple(
    'Truck',
    [
        'brand',
        'photo_file_name',
        'body_whl',
        'carrying'
    ]
)


def get_car_list(path):
    car_list = []
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        csv_file = csv.reader(file)
        for row in csv_file:
            car_params = row[0].split(';')
            if car_params[0] == 'car':
                car = Car(brand=car_params[1],
                          passenger_seats_count=car_params[2],
                          photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                          carrying=car_params[5])
                car_list.append(car)
            elif car_params[0] == 'truck':
                car = Truck(brand=car_params[1],
                            photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                            body_whl=car_params[4],
                            carrying=car_params[5])
                car_list.append(car)
            elif car_params[0] == 'spec_machine':
                car = SpecMachine(brand=car_params[1],
                                  photo_file_name=car_params[3],
                                  carrying=car_params[5],
                                  extra=car_params[6])
                car_list.append(car)
    return car_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_car_list('test.csv'))

# [Car(brand='Nissan xTtrail', passenger_seats_count='4', photo_file_name='f1.jpeg', carrying='2.5'), Truck(brand='Man', photo_file_name='f2.png', body_whl='8x3x2.5', carrying='20'), Truck(brand='Man', photo_file_name='f2.png', body_whl='', carrying='20'), Car(brand='Mazda 6', passenger_seats_count='4', photo_file_name='f3.jpeg', carrying='2.5'), SpecMachine(brand='Hitachi', photo_file_name='f4', carrying='1.2', extra='Легкая техника для уборки снега')]
```

Входные данные тоже не менял, вот содержимое `test.csv`:

```
car_type;brand;passenger_seats_count;photo_file_name;body_whl;carrying;extra
car;Nissan xTtrail;4;f1.jpeg;;2.5;
truck;Man;;f2.png;8x3x2.5;20;
truck;Man;;f2.png;;20;
car;Mazda 6;4;f3.jpeg;;2.5;
;;;
spec_machine;Hitachi;;f4;;1.2;Легкая техника для уборки снега
```

> Думаю, что проблема в данных находящихся вне того примера который Вы дали.
> Для того, чтобы попробовать решить проблему, желательно иметь ту часть данных при обработке которых возникает исключение.

Comment: Я правил свой вопрос и прикрепил полный код

Comment: @VladislavChevtaev Как уже написали в комментариях к вопросу, ошибка на предоставленных данных не воспроизводится даже с полным кодом. (

Comment: Так ошибка же выбрасывается на этих данных. Либо я чего то не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Оказывается цикл читал пустые строки в csv файле и после этого выкидывал out of range.
Всем спасибо!